# How to avoid / work around PHP wordwrap removing spaces

Tags: php, string, formatting, icalendar, word-wrap

For an iCal generator that I'm working on, I need to ensure that each 75 characters, a string is broken like this:

```
$string = "This is a long text. I use this text to demonstrate the PHP wordwrap function.";
$newstring = wordwrap($string, 75, "\r\n ", TRUE);

echo($newstring);
```

Result:

```
This is a long text. I use this text to demonstrate the PHP wordwrap
 function.
```

iCal interprets the first space (from the wordwrap break parameter) as an indicator that the text property continues.

The wordwrap function removed the second space (from the string). After decoding the iCal content, the text would therefore look like this:

```
This is a long text. I use this text to demonstrate the PHP wordwrapfunction.
```

How can I work around this? I don't want the space from the string (between "wordwrap" and "function") to be removed.

Answer (score 2):

I have to use `chunk_split` instead. It will preserve the space and also not try to wrap at a space, which I don't need.

```
$string = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaannnnnn";
$newstring = rtrim(chunk_split($string, 75, "\r\n "), "\r\n ");

echo($newstring);
```

Space preserved:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaannnnnn
```

`rtrim` is also used, as `chunk_split` always appends `end`.

This won't count the space within `end`, however. So if there are multiple lines, one could actually be 76 chars long. I changed the `chunklen` parameter to 74, as this is good enough for my use case.

Comment: chunk_split will cut the words

Answer (score 1):

Ok, While doing wordwrap pass an additional space so, that space between wordwrap and function will be retained.

Use this

```
$newstring = wordwrap($string, 75, " \r\n", TRUE);
```

Instead of

```
$newstring = wordwrap($string, 75, "\r\n", TRUE);
```

Output Before iCal:

```
This is a long text. I use this text to demonstrate the PHP wordwrap 
function.
```

Output After iCal:

```
This is a long text. I use this text to demonstrate the PHP wordwrap function.
```

Answer (score 0):

It will always remove spaces, it's better to do your own function.

This function will also ignore HTML tags:

```
function shyLongWords($str, $len = 40) {
    $str = preg_replace_callback('#((?:(?!<[/a-z]).)*)([^>]*>|$)#si', function($m) use ($co, $len) {
        $x = '';
        foreach (explode(' ', $m[1]) as $i => $part) {
            $x.= ($i == 0 ? '' : ' ').implode("&shy;", str_split($part, $len));
        }
        return $x . $m[2];
    }, $str);
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to return `$str`, just return the returned string from `preg_replace_callback()`.  Why `&shy;`?

Comment: @mickmackusa  `&shy;` breaks long words... you could use CSS for that, but CSS would break the sentences.